# Bash script log file rotation

Tags: bash, file, rotation, logging

My bash script produces a log file. Now i'd like to implement some log file rotation.
 Let's say the first time it's called **somelog.log**, the next time it's renamed to **somelog.log.1** and the new log file **somelog.log**.
The third time the new log is **somelog.log** again, but **somelog.log.1** is renamed to **somelog.log.2** and the old **somelog.log** to **somelog.log.1**.
I would be able to grant a maximum of eg 5.
 Is this done before (sample script), any suggestions. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: man [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) ?

Comment: Already answered. [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690936/change-file-name-suffixes-using-sed/3691279#3691279

Answer (score 3):

Try this bash function, it takes two parameters:

1. number of maximum megabyte the file should exceed to be rotated (otherwise is let untouched)
2. full path of the filename.

source:

```
function rotate () {
  # minimum file size to rotate in MBi:
  local MB="$1"
  # filename to rotate (full path)
  local F="$2"
  local msize="$((1024*1024*${MB}))"
  test -e "$F" || return 2

  local D="$(dirname "$F")"
  local E=${F##*.}
  local B="$(basename "$F" ."$E")"

  local s=

  echo "rotate msize=$msize file=$F -> $D | $B | $E"
  if [ "$(stat --printf %s "$F")" -ge $msize ] ; then
     for i in 8 9 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0; do 
       s="$D/$B-$i.$E"
       test -e "$s" && mv $s "$D/$B-$((i+1)).$E"
  # emtpy command is need to avoid exit iteration if test fails:
       :;
     done &&
     mv $F $D/$B-0.$E
  else
     echo "rotate skip: $F < $msize, skip"
  fi
  return $?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just made a bash script for that:
https://github.com/lingtalfi/logrotator

It basically checks your log file's size, and if it exceeds an arbitrary threshold, it copies the log file into a log directory.

It's cron friendly, or you can use it manually too.

A typical command looks like that:

```
> ./logrotator.sh -f private/log -m {fileName}.{datetime}.txt -v
```