# Shell script Rotate files while the file keep on updating with data

Tags: bash, logging

I need a shell script to rotate logs files while its updating continuously.

```
#!/bin/bash
log-file=$1
if [ ! -f $log-file ]; then
  echo "log file not found $log-file"
  exit 1
fi
times-tamp=`date +%Y%m%d`
new-log-file=$log-file.$time-stamp
cp $log-file $new-log-file
cat /dev/null > $log-file
gzip -f -9 $new-log-file
```

I want to know the in flight messages status  during the copy of messages from log file to new log file?

Will those messages loss? if we loss in-flight messages then how can I do rotation of those files.

Can some one help me to understand it?

Comment: Not sure if it is what you need but my way is to create daily files and delete 5 day older ones with `find ./ -name log* -mtime +5 -delete`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script log file rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690015/bash-script-log-file-rotation)

Answer (score 2):

There are utilities providing support for message logging.
Beside the suggested `logrotate`, I usually use `syslogd` to rotate files when they reach a desired maximum dimension.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the process that write to the log.
the best way is to move the logfile to new location, create the new file and send some signal to the process using the log that will force it to start using the new file 
like:

```
mv log log.1
touch log
kill -HUP `pgrep -f process_using_the_log`
```

but you better to use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)
Apache logrotate example:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
    endscript
    prerotate
            if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                    run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
            fi; \
    endscript
    }
```