# Get the newly added data from a txt file every $X minutes

Tags: bash, shell, timing

I have a command that is continually adding IPs (do not know the quantity) to a txt file called ips.txt

```
shodan stream --alert=all --datadir=. --compresslevel=0 >> ips.txt
```

I want to get the newly added data to the ips.txt file every 1 hour and make some bash operations on it as I will leave this command running in the background.

How can I get only the newly added data to this file every time automatically?

Comment: You'll simplify your life if you just get a new file each hour and then append it after done processing to you "archive" version of the file, i.e. `shodan stream .... > newFile ; while read line ; do echo "your processing of $line goes here" ; done <newFile ; cat newFile >> archiveFIle && /bin/rm newFile` or something like that. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690015/bash-script-log-file-rotation

Comment: Unless you can modify your `shodan` command, the "best" way would be to take every hour a snap of `ips.txt` and do a `diff` to the most recent snapshot. Of course this will take more time, the larger ips.txt grows. If you can modify the command, don't redirct directly to ips.txt, but pipe it through a script, which (like `cat`) copies stdin to stdout, but in addition processes the most recent IP addresses in the way you like, based on the current time (i.e. collects the data for one hour, and then does the processing).

Comment: You could use a cache file to store last file size, then use `tail -c +$lastSize ips.txt` to read new events...

Comment: `I have a command that is continually adding IPs` - unless there's some important detail you haven't told us about how IPs get removed from that file, that's going to eventually consume every byte of available space on your computer which would probably be undesirable.

Comment: Hi @user1934428, I can actually edit the command, can you please elaborate the code as I really do not get your point?

Comment: Hi shellter, where should I put my sleep time as I want to get only the new data every 1 hour for example and make some bash script on it.

Comment: @ELMO : You do a `shodan ... | splitter >ips.txt`, and your script `splitter` (which you have to write) just copies each line from stdin into stdout AND also copies the line to, say, `ips_last_hour.txt`. Once the current time is more than 1 hour past the creation time of `ips_last_hour.txt`, you process this file (which contains the information from the last hour), then erase it, and create it freshly. Therefore, after each hour you are processing the information from the past hour (only).

Comment: If the output of `shodan` is not that complex, you could alternatively just store the lines of the past hour into a bash array and then process the array. Since you didn't describe what kind of "operations" you want to perform, I can't tell which way is easier. In any case, ips.txt will in the end still contain the full output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ipsFile="$1"

trap 'trap - SIGTERM && kill 0' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

shodan() { ( while :; do date; sleep 1; done; ) & }

shodan > "$ipsFile"

endWc=0
while :; do
    sleep 3
    begWc=$(( endWc + 1 ))
    endWc=$(wc -l < "$ipsFile")
    if (( endWc > 0 )); then
        if (( endWc < begWc )); then
            begWc=1
        fi
        newWc=$(( endWc - begWc + 1 ))
        echo "----- $begWc -> $endWc = $newWc lines"
        tail -n +"$begWc" "$ipsFile" |
        head -n +"$newWc"
    fi
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh ips.txt
----- 1 -> 3 = 3 lines
Wed Nov  8 08:20:04 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:05 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:06 CST 2023
----- 4 -> 6 = 3 lines
Wed Nov  8 08:20:08 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:09 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:10 CST 2023
----- 7 -> 8 = 2 lines
Wed Nov  8 08:20:12 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:13 CST 2023
----- 9 -> 11 = 3 lines
Wed Nov  8 08:20:14 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:15 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:17 CST 2023
----- 12 -> 14 = 3 lines
Wed Nov  8 08:20:18 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:19 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:21 CST 2023
Terminated
```

```
$ cat ips.txt
Wed Nov  8 08:20:04 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:05 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:06 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:08 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:09 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:10 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:12 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:13 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:14 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:15 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:17 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:18 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:19 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:21 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:22 CST 2023
Wed Nov  8 08:20:23 CST 2023
```

The `shodan()` function is to mimic what your `shodan` command is doing and the `trap` is to kill the `shodan()` child process on exit so we can test the main part of the code, the final loop.

I'm using `wc` specifically as it counts newlines in it's input so if somehow `shodan` could have written a partial line at the end of ips.txt it won't get picked up until the next loop iteration when it's a complete line. That's also why I'm piping the `tail` output to a subsequent `head`, to ensure we just get those complete lines. I'm also using `tail | head` instead of, say, a single `awk` command as tail reads from the end of the file and so will be more efficient for this than awk which always starts at the beginning.

The `if (( endWc < begWc ))` block is to start printing from the first line again if the file shrunk - that may or may not be what you want to do in that situation, idk. You'll also want to add a bit of code to do whatever you want to do if the files is empty (`if (( endWc > 0 ))` fails) on any iteration and think about whether or not there are any other rainy-day scenarios to cover.

I interrupt `./tst.sh` to stop it, and the `cat ips.txt` has a couple of extra lines as `shodan()` runs once per second so the main "every 3 seconds" loop (obviously change that to `sleep 3600` or do whatever else you like to sleep for an hour) hasn't processed all the lines at that point. The important thing is that no lines are missing from the output prior to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made function ``shodan()
{
shodan stream --alert=all --datadir=. --compresslevel=0
}``

and leave all the other code as it is (except increasing the sleep) but when I ran it, an error appears ``Segmentation fault``

Comment: You're welcome. Whatever is causing that is a separate issue, ask a new question about that.